# Designing a dynamic panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am new to C# and I want to design a GUI for a image processing application in c#.  I have a very basic rudimentary layout designed as shown below[image]

Here, the image plane is fixed and it will show a live stream video. I have designed all the buttons frame and the side panel. But I do not know how to dynamically change the side panel for each button I click. For example, If I click button1_1, I want some things in the side panel and for button1_2, some other things in it. How do I go about doing it.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers. I see tab controls is an option. But I want a new panel evertime a click a button. which can further open forms. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have your heart set on WinForms, or would you consider WPF?

Comment: I heard WPF needs more time. I want to do it winforms since it has a simpler learning curve for other programmers after me who are maintaining my code. since we use different languages in our company.

Comment: You're right, WPF is generally considered to have a steeper learning curve.  On the other hand, it has better data binding and allows for better separation between presentation and application logic.  If you go to the effort of creating a test suite for your application, future maintainers will probably be much more grateful for that than for using WinForms.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, let's see. It's easy to do with "TabControl" or array of "Panel"s.

1.Do it with TabControl.
You can design GUI in TabControl in multiple subTabs(if you don't know how please ask.). Then you change it in button click event, to make subTab you wanna show(which means make it visiable and not visiable for other subTabs.)

2.Do it with array of panel.
You can use panel[] panels. In button click event, you hide other panels and show the one you want.

Hope answer helps you!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text = "First";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some tutorials or sources for tabcontrol and array of panels.. Thanks.:)

Comment: Sorry for bading looking.private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
}

Comment: I edit in my answer, hope you can understand, it just change the SelectedIndex of the tabcontrol.

Comment: Thanks. I implementented it. But I want to display some dynamic heading for each tab. Anyway I can do that?

Comment: @shivoham Yes. tabControl1.TabPages[index].Text="Title";

Comment: Thanks. I did that before. But the title is not getting displayed. Am I missing something here.?

Comment: @shivoham It works fine in my VS..Can you show your parts of code so I can see if something you missed.I made a example in my answer.

Comment: I am using this code to make the tabes invisible. so I am not getting any headings.  tabControl1.Region = new Region(tabControl1.DisplayRectangle);

Answer (score 2):

you may want to add split container in your form.

Create UserControl for each buttons.

Code for the button click event

```
//Button1Click Event
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 m_UserControl = new UserControl1();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(m_UserControl);
    }
    //Button2Click Event
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl2 m_Usercontrol2 = new UserControl2();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(m_Usercontrol2);
    }
```

you can do this if you want to change what usercontrol display in a panel at run time.
Correct me if i misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms, you could use a tab control and just change the selected tabs index when a button is pressed. More specifically, when its click event is fired. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/TabControlTutorial11302005235835PM/TabControlTutorial.aspx) is a good tutorial on using the TabControl and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) is a tutorial on wiring up click events.

**EDIT:**

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/c-sharp-tabcontrol/) is a better tutorial.

Since you can't hide the tabs of a tabcontrol without using WPF, you may need to use something else, if you don't like the way they look. A good workaround if you only have a couple of buttons and thus views, would be to use panels. When button one is clicked show panel one and hide panel two, etc. Here would be the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pane2.visible = false;
        pane1.visible = true;
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pane1.visible = false;
        pane2.visible = true;
    }
```

Hope this helps you!